# Need help getting Fine Uploader PHP server example working

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, fine-uploader

I just bought fine-uploader but I can't get it work. I want to use it with xampp and php, without s3.

This is the index.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <link href="fineuploader-3.8.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="fine-uploader">
  </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.fineuploader-3.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    // Wait until the DOM is 'ready'
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
            debug: true,
            request: {
                endpoint: 'php.php'
            },
            retry: {
               enableAuto: true
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then the php.php from the server repository:

```
 <?php

    // list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
    $allowedExtensions = array();
    // max file size in bytes
    $sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    //require('fine-uploader/server/php.php');
    $uploader = new qqFileUploader($allowedExtensions, $sizeLimit);

    // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads/');

    // to pass data through iframe you will need to encode all html tags
    echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);

    /**
     * Handle file uploads via XMLHttpRequest
     */
    class qqUploadedFileXhr {
    ...
```

The uploads Folder exists and is writeable (as I'm working local). So what's the problem?
Do I need the qqFileUploader.php somehow, which is also in the repository?

Can anyone provide a working example with php?

Thank you very much and kind regards

Netik

Comment: There is a PHP example in the server-side repo.  You should base your PHP code off of that.  https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server.  Of course you need all of the files in the PHP example in the server repo, except for the items in the S3 directory, since you are not uploading to S3.

Comment: You would also do well to give us some more details on where it's failing - stack trace, error message, etc

Comment: > Do I need the qqFileUploader.php somehow, which is also in the repository? YES.

Comment: Ray, I downloaded all the files from the server rep. However, I really don't see how these 3 files are connected together and there is simply no explanation or description. qqFileUploader.php seems to be the class of the update handler, in the example.php it is included --> require_once 'qqFileUploader.php', but what is the purpose of php.php? Inside of the php.php, there is a require('php.php') which makes no sense to me. And what should be the request endpoint, php.php or example.php?

When I select a file, it says "processing file" but then fails. have to try to get more logs/traces..

Comment: Yea, that example is a mess.  It was patched together over years of 3rd-party contributions.  We have a case open to fix that, but we'll make it a priority and start working on that very soon.  In fact, I'm going to aim to have that adjusted during this current release cycle.  You can track work on that case here: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/issues/12.

Comment: Thanks Ray. So, right now, nobody has a working example with php? I don't even need many features, just a simple upload.

Comment: There are a lot of Fine Uploader users with a PHP backend.  I'd say that is likely the most popular server-side language for users of this library.  However, we don't use it internally which is why the example has decayed.  I'm starting work on a complete-reorg of this example now, and hope to have it done by mid-next-week.  I'm sure others have use the example with success, but not without some frustrating integration work required to make sense of it....

Comment: You can either wait until I am finished reworking the example, try to make some sense of it yourself (most of the logic there is likely all sound but just poorly organized and commented), or attempt to write your own PHP endpoint by following the directions in the [traditional endpoint handler documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html).

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised that I haven't seen more comments about the existing PHP example, which is why I haven't really made an effort to "fix" it yet.  In most cases, users are simply stuck on one piece, which I can easily assist with.  The S3 examples are all written by us, and the plan is to rework all of the non-S3 examples as well, since most of those are user-contributed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot Ray Nicholus. If anyone else has a working example already, I would be very happy, till the official examles get reorganzied. Unfortunately my php skills are terrible.

Comment: If you don't want to wait, is there any reason you have to use PHP?  Perhaps you would have better luck with the Node example.  Or event the Java example (which was written by me).

Comment: Hmm I believe our webhoster only supports PHP, plus the website where it should get integrated is based on the code-igniter framework already.

Comment: Good enough.  We'll i'll add commits and comments to the case I referenced as I work through the existing PHP example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP example should be much easier to follow now.  I adjusted the documentation, removed some redundant and unnecessary files, and re-organized the directory structure.  Now, for traditional endpoints (such as yours), you should point your client-side endpoints at the ["endpoint.php" file](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional/endpoint.php), which requires the ["handler.php" file](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional/handler.php).  The Widen-supported php example is located in the [root of the php/traditional directory](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/php/traditional) in the [Widen/fine-uploader-server repo on Github](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server).  There are also examples for S3 endpoints (in the php/s3 directory), and the Lithium framework (not maintained by Widen, but located in php/traditional/li3).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working before as it really wasn't difficult which speaks for fineuploader. Thanks anyway I'm sure it will help other users too!

Comment: Can I please please please be guided to use fine-uploader (since I see it's an amazing library). I am an iOS developer and have only minimum knowledge on PHP and have successfully created an iOS app that acts as an http and bonjour server with the use of CocoaHTTPServer, but now I need to make a clean and nice implementation for the server UI.

Comment: @danipralea If you have a specific question regarding use of Fine Uploader, please open up a question under the fine-uploader tag here on Stack Overflow.